# cURL use Non-SSL Proxy to get SSL page

Tags: curl

I am currently using cURL to POST some data to a SSL page (https://...). I am using the `-x` flag to have it go through a different IP. Unfortunately, this IP does not support SSL. Is there anyway I can use cURL to still POST the data even though SSL is not supported?

Edit: I am using the curl command, not PHP or any other language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing SSL (or TLS rather) with a remote site over a HTTP proxy, the only way to do this is to send a HTTP CONNECT request to the proxy and have it setup a tunnel to the remote site.

curl will then connect over that tunnel and speak TLS. So, the proxy itself does not know or handle any TLS but it needs to support CONNECT appropriately. HTTP CONNECT is a standard part of the HTTP specification. Nothing magic.

This is thus what curl does when you do `curl -x [proxy] https://[url]`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps :)

> Yeah, you can do that, as curl --help or man curl would have told you:
>
> -k, --insecure
>
> (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL
>   connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be
>   made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default.
>   This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k,
>   --insecure is used.
>
> See this online resource for further details:
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/469824/curl-disable-certificate-verification

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I am using the curl command on UNIX. Not PHP

Comment: I don't know why I assumed it was PHP. I guess it's because I see posts like this for PHP so often.

Comment: I am getting "Proxy CONNECT Aborted". My command is currently `curl -k -x IP:PORT https://SITE`

Comment: Try adding -D to your curl command to show the response headers. You should get some more information out of that. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It just times out. I do not think it is possible.

Comment: `-k` option doesn't have any link with using a non-SSL proxy, it's related to self signed certificate.